# How to Keep Users Logged In to App in ionic 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

**I have dought How to Keep Users Logged In to the App  in ionic 4 ,I had done some work like storing the credentials like email and and cross-check the user in using api and the redirecting to the menu page but I am getting the login page for a few seconds and then redirecting to the menu page how to solve this, Actually its should directly open the menu page.**

**app-routing.modules.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then(m => m.HomePageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'assign',
    loadChildren: () => import('./assign/assign.module').then( m => m.AssignPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then( m => m.LoginPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    loadChildren: () => import('./register/register.module').then( m => m.RegisterPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'view',
    loadChildren: () => import('./view/view.module').then( m => m.ViewPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'view-routes',
    loadChildren: () => import('./view-routes/view-routes.module').then( m => m.ViewRoutesPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'view-orders',
    loadChildren: () => import('./view-orders/view-orders.module').then( m => m.ViewOrdersPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'view-customers',
    loadChildren: () => import('./view-customers/view-customers.module').then( m => m.ViewCustomersPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'view-leads',
    loadChildren: () => import('./view-leads/view-leads.module').then( m => m.ViewLeadsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'view-team',
    loadChildren: () => import('./view-team/view-team.module').then( m => m.ViewTeamPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'view-channel-partners',
    loadChildren: () => import('./view-channel-partners/view-channel-partners.module').then( m => m.ViewChannelPartnersPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'my-profile',
    loadChildren: () => import('./my-profile/my-profile.module').then( m => m.MyProfilePageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'customer-details',
    loadChildren: () => import('./customer-details/customer-details.module').then( m => m.CustomerDetailsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'add-customer',
    loadChildren: () => import('./add-customer/add-customer.module').then( m => m.AddCustomerPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'leadetails',
    loadChildren: () => import('./leadetails/leadetails.module').then( m => m.LeadetailsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'updatedetails',
    loadChildren: () => import('./updatedetails/updatedetails.module').then( m => m.UpdatedetailsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'orderdetails',
    loadChildren: () => import('./orderdetails/orderdetails.module').then( m => m.OrderdetailsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'search',
    loadChildren: () => import('./search/search.module').then( m => m.SearchPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'otp',
    loadChildren: () => import('./otp/otp.module').then( m => m.OtpPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'reminders',
    loadChildren: () => import('./reminders/reminders.module').then( m => m.RemindersPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'create-lead',
    loadChildren: () => import('./create-lead/create-lead.module').then( m => m.CreateLeadPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'add-update',
    loadChildren: () => import('./add-update/add-update.module').then( m => m.AddUpdatePageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'add-order',
    loadChildren: () => import('./add-order/add-order.module').then( m => m.AddOrderPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'about-customer',
    loadChildren: () => import('./about-customer/about-customer.module').then( m => m.AboutCustomerPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'Orders',
    loadChildren: () => import('./orders/orders.module').then( m => m.OrdersPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'billdetails',
    loadChildren: () => import('./billdetails/billdetails.module').then( m => m.BilldetailsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'cust-det',
    loadChildren: () => import('./cust-det/cust-det.module').then( m => m.CustDetPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'logout',
    loadChildren: () => import('./logout/logout.module').then( m => m.LogoutPageModule)
  }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**service**

```js
 this.http.get('https://www.url.com/App_1.3.5/login.php?compid=' + Companyid + '&username=' + Userid + '&password=' + Password + '&deviceID=' + deviceid + '&latitude=' + lat + '&longitude=' + lot + '&version='+ this.version +'&brand='+ this.manufacturer +'&model='+ this.model +'').subscribe(data => {
    this.response = data;
    this.authenticationState.next(true);
    this.displayUsername();
    this.userid = Userid;
    console.log(data);
    });

******************************************************************

async displayUsername() {
  // console.log(this.response.compid, this.response.role);
  const result = this.response.result;
  this.compDomain = this.response.compDomain;
  if (result === 'success') {
    this.set('ocompid',  this.response.compid);
    this.set('ocompname',  this.response.comp_name);
    this.set('orole',  this.response.role);
    this.set('ocity',  this.response.city);
    this.set('ocompDomain',  this.response.compDomain);
    this.set('ocomp_type',  this.response.comp_type);
   
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/view-customers');// giving access to menu page
  } else {
    const toast = await this.toastController.create({
      message: result,
      position: 'bottom',
      duration: 1500
    });
    toast.present();
    // alert(result);
  }
```

**this also service redirecting to menue page after cross check**

```js
if(this.scmpid != undefined && this.suserid != undefined ) {

    this.http.get('https://www.url.com/App_1.3.5/Executive/get_executive_status.php?compid='+ this.scmpid +'&username='+ this.suserid +'&appVersion='+ this.appVersion +'&Device_Id='+ this.ud.uuid +'').subscribe(data => {
    this.logres = data['result'];
    // alert(this.logres);+' '+
    if( this.logres == 'success') {
      alert('3'+ this.logres);
      console.log('success');   
      this.cmpid = this.scmpid;
      this.userid = this.suserid;
      this.authenticationState.next(true);
    }
    
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

*So I thought of a simple solution fro this problem *

- As while we opening the app while user is logged in its showing login page for few seconds

**so I am hidding the contents of the login page if the user is logged in**

**login.html**

```html
<ion-content *ngIf='logged == true'>
  <img src="" alt="">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <img src="assets/img/serviceho.png" alt="" srcset="">
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah Above answer worked according to your scenario. But generally you have to use auth-guard and use function `canLoad()` of angular. It should be called `ngOnInit()` of app component

Comment: kk I will try that tq fro reply